# MongoDB with ElasticSearch mapping with Mongoosastic

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I'm trying to index an existing collection to ElasticSearch using the mongoosastic plugin for NodeJs. This my schema:

```
const callCenterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _owner : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', es_type: 'object' },
    ivrs: [{
        name: {
            type: String,
            es_type: 'string'
        },
        ivrType: {
            type: String,
            default: 'mobile',
            enum: ['mobile', 'website'],
            es_type: 'string'
        },
        submenu: {
            type: [ CallCenterSubmenu.schema ],
            es_type: 'nested',
            es_include_in_parent: true
        }
    }]
});

callCenterSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    esClient: require('tusla/lib/db/elastic').elastic,
    populate: [
        { path: '_owner' }
    ]
});

let CallCenter = mongoose.model('CallCenter', callCenterSchema);
CallCenter.synchronize()

CallCenter.createMapping(function(err, mapping) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error creating mapping for CallCenters', err.message);
  }
});


module.exports = CallCenter;
```

My submenu schema is like this:

```
const callcenterSubmenuSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    key: String,
    waitTime: {
        type: Number
    },
    waitSuffix: String,
    numberOrLink: String,
    auth: {
        canBeSkipped: String,
        fields: {
            type: Array,
            es_type: 'object'
        },
        verification: String,
        regExp: String
    },
    submenu: [this]
}, { _id: false });
```

I keep getting this specific error, but couldn't solve it. I appreciate if you guys can help me.

Thanks!

Error creating mapping for CallCenters [mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type [mixed] declared on field [submenu]

Comment: What is CallCenterSubmenu.schema?

Comment: I've given the submenu schema on below the first schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that line:

```
 type: [ CallCenterSubmenu.schema ]
```

In error message it says:

```
No handler for type [mixed] declared on field [submenu]
```

So you are trying to specify the type of `submenu` field as `fixed` (or elasticsearch infers it as I am not sure) and as I know there is no type as `mixed`. So ES fires that exception. You must specify a valid type: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/mapping-types.html